# Hibernate SessionFactory Annotation Error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

Getting this error. Tried everything to resolve it. Looked through tonns of similar questions, but no result. Maybe one of you guys may spot the error? Thank you in advance.

**Error log:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: miniVLE.dao.MiniVLEDAOImplementation miniVLE.service.StudentService.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'miniVLEDAOImplementation': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory miniVLE.dao.MiniVLEDAOImplementation.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My dispatcher-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.beans" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.dao" />
   <!-- <mvc:annotation-driven />-->
    <!--tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /-->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <!-- Declare a view resolver-->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />


    <!-- Connects to the database based on the jdbc properties information-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class ="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name ="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name ="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/minivledb"/>
        <property name ="username" value="root"/>
        <property name ="password" value="123" />
    </bean>

     <!-- Declares hibernate object -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> ${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <!-- A list of all the annotated bean files, which are mapped with database tables-->
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value> miniVLE.beans.Course </value>
                <value> miniVLE.beans.Student </value>
                <value> miniVLE.beans.Department </value>  
                <value> miniVLE.beans.Module </value>  
                <value> miniVLE.beans.TimeSlot </value> 
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My DAO class implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import miniVLE.beans.Course;
import miniVLE.beans.Department;
import miniVLE.beans.Module;
import miniVLE.beans.Student;
import miniVLE.beans.TimeSlot;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public class MiniVLEDAOImplementation implements MiniVLEDAO{

    // Used for communicating with the database
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory; ...
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    MiniVLEDAOImplementation dao;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh... Really silly mistake! Make sure you are no doubling this in applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.beans" />
<context:component-scan base-package="miniVLE.dao" />
```

Gosh.. I killed a day trying to resolve it!